# Magento 2 error in swatchRenderer.js

Tags: magento2, product, javascript, swatches

I have overridden magento `SwatchRenderer.js` file in `app\code\Mydirectory\CustomSwatches\view\frontend\web\js\SwatchRenderer.js`.

My problem is I get an error in my product page load:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined

I found out that `data('gallery')` on `SwatchRenderer.js`'s following function is undefined.

```
updateBaseImage: function (images, context, isProductViewExist) {
        var justAnImage = images[0];

        if (isProductViewExist) {
            context
                .find('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]')
                .data('gallery')
                .updateData(images);
        } else if (justAnImage && justAnImage.img) {
            context.find('.product-image-photo').attr('src', justAnImage.img);
        }
    }
```

I checked a Magento 2 demo site. On that site the above data attribute is set as a JavaScript object. The target element is a div with the above attribute. But in my site it is undefined and obviously I think that data attribute is not set on my site. Can anyone help me to find the setter function/view/file for above element? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How you overwrite this SwatchRenderer.js. Show your overwrite script and all code SwatchRenderer.js

Comment: Which is exactly your Magento version?

Comment: @Khoa My magento version is 2.0.4 updated from 2.0.2. This issue is in both versions.

Comment: You can upload your full code on github or here.

Comment: Hi @JanakaDombawela are you have this on Product Page or Category Listings - are you trying to use Product image switching from colours? If so, please post full code and what your trying to do. The reason I am asking is I had the same issue but I coded around this to fix it and made an AJAX swatcher

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have the code with me now. I'll upload it asap.

Answer (score 1):

We had this same issue until we realized we were hiding the price of products on our category listing page. Apparently, `swatch-renderer.js` relies on classes on the price box to determine if it is on the product view or product listing page. After re-enabling the price box, color swatch switching started working again.